# Wordpress: show featured image with subcategory

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I'm using this to generate a list of sub-pages that are a parent of 10 and images:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=10&link_after=<img src="http://mydomain.com/image.gif" alt="" />'); ?>
</ul>
```

It works, but the problem is I don't know how to get the post **featured image** there instead. I tried this but it did not work:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=10&link_after=<img src="' . the_post_thumbnail(array(100,50)) . '" alt="" />'); ?>
```

Obviously I'm missing something.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display the page titles along with the images, you should use `get_pages()`

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of=10');
if ($pages) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">';
        echo get_the_title($page->ID);
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID);
        echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_the_post_thumbnail` function returns HTML not the image url.

Instead use

```
<?php $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(10), array(100,50) ); ?>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=10&link_after=<img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="" />'); ?>
```

This will list all sub-pages of page id 10, with thumbnail of page id 10. If you want the thumbnails of the sub-pages instead of parent page, you will have to write custom code instead of `wp_list_pages` function(as explained by Indranil).